# Repository Not Being Initiated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javabeans, java-11, spring-annotations

I am getting an error when trying to move my repository initiation from my Application class to a config class. It seems strange because the urlRepository.save call does not throw, while the urlRepository.findAll() gets a null. What am I doing wrong here?

### Before (Works Fine - prints to console with the preloaded URL)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UrlShortenerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
private UrlRepository urlRepository = new MongoUrlRepository();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(UrlShortenerApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

    String shortlinkStub = "short.li/";
    String cascadeDishPods = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07CTQ8THP/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1";
    String flipFlops = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0013MWDO0/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1";
    urlRepository.save(new ShortUrl(shortlinkStub + "flipflops", flipFlops));
    urlRepository.findAll().forEach(shortUrl -> System.out.println("Preloaded " + shortUrl));
}
}
```

### After (null pointer exception for repository.findAll())

*ShortenerConfig.java*

```
@Configuration
public class ShortenerConfig {

public static UrlRepository urlRepository = new MongoUrlRepository();

@Bean("urlRepo")
public UrlRepository urlRepo() {
    return urlRepository;
}
}
```

*UrlShortenerApplication.java*

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class UrlShortenerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("urlRepo")
    private UrlRepository urlRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(UrlShortenerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        String shortlinkStub = "short.li/";
        String cascadeDishPods = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07CTQ8THP/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1";
        String flipFlops = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0013MWDO0/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1";
        urlRepository.save(new ShortUrl(shortlinkStub + "flipflops", flipFlops));
        urlRepository.findAll().forEach(shortUrl -> System.out.println("Preloaded " + shortUrl));
    }
}
```

That last line throws a null pointer exception and I don't know why!

### Stacktrace

line 22 refers to the "run" and line 35 refers to the reponsitory.findAll()

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-12 10:48:25.813 ERROR 75530 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.urlshortener.UrlShortenerApplication.main(UrlShortenerApplication.java:22) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.example.urlshortener.UrlShortenerApplication.run(UrlShortenerApplication.java:35) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted

2020-06-12 10:48:25.843  INFO 75530 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

### Repository Interface and Class (For Both Cases)

```
public interface UrlRepository extends MongoRepository<ShortUrl, Long> {
    public ShortUrl findByShortUrl(String shortUrl); 
    public List<ShortUrl> findByLongUrl(String longUrl);
```

}

```
public class MongoUrlRepository implements UrlRepository {
    @Override
    public ShortUrl findByShortUrl(String shortUrl) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<ShortUrl> findByLongUrl(String longUrl) {
        return null;
    }
```

....

Comment: Please add stacktrace.

Comment: Added the stacktrace

Comment: By any chance `findAll` returns null?

Comment: It doesn't throw a null pointer in the first instance - it prints to the console with the "flip flops" url I had just saved.

Comment: please show your UrlRepository

Comment: @silentsudo added!

Comment: are you implementing findAll in your MongoUrlRepository the same way (simply returning null)?

Comment: Why are you annotating fields with `@Autowired`, but also create an instance with new?

Comment: @JensSchauder In the first working example or the second?

Comment: @gadget - yes, I am

Comment: You only do it in the first example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoUrlRepository supposed to be an interface, that's the way Spring could manage it's crud implementations automatically. Since you are declaring it as a class you basically overriding the builtin finder methods to just return null, that's where your NPE is coming from.

see the examples from spring.io:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Why it worked in the 1st case:

```
@Autowired
private UrlRepository urlRepository = new MongoUrlRepository();
```

You instantiate a MongoUrlRepository, however that object will be replaced during dependency injection and since you're not specifying a qualifier spring will build a managed MongoRepository bean (based on your UrlRepository interface) and ignore your MongoUrlRepository class.